# I can't resolve User-defined type not defined when using XMLHTTPRequest in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I used the following code in my excel VBA module, but the error message was that user-defined type not defined. Any idea what is wrong? I am on Windows 10.

```
Public Sub XmlHttpTutorial()

Dim xmlhttp As Object
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")

Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.xmlhttp
xmlhttp.Open Method, URL, async(True Or False)

Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, myurl As String
myurl = "http://requestb.in/15oxrjh1" //replace with your URL
xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
xmlhttp.Send
MsgBox (xmlhttp.responseText)


End Sub
```

Comment: Just wondering... but why are you declaring variable `xmlhttp` 3 times? And everytime is different

Comment: I am not familiar with the xmlhttprequest method.

Comment: What line returns the error?

Comment: @TingPing myurl is your real url ? did you change it ?

Comment: Have you added "Microsoft XML, v6.0" as a reference using Tools > References in the VBA editor?